# Ubuntu does not provide Clang's stdint which contains uint24_t type

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, clang

I need to have a 3 byte unsigned integer type. When I look into clang's include path /usr/include/clang/3.5/include the stdint provides a uint24_t data type. But when I want to use it, clang compiler raise an error (error: unknown type name 'uint24_t';)!

```
#include "stdint.h"
int main()
{
   uint24_t a = 12;
   return 0;
}
```

Would you please help on how to compile and utilize 24 bit integers in clang?

Comment: Do you include the cstdint header?

Comment: I have included "stdint.h" instead.

Comment: Just because you see something in the file that defines something called `uint24_t` doesn't mean that you will get the definition of this type if you `include` it. I'm sure there's a bunch of ifdefs/ifndefs in there, that selectively skip over chunks of the include file that are not available on your hardware platform. The `uint24_t` type is probably available only on some other CPU type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's why it's not included in my system!

Comment: Seems like a relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16377903/4299382

Comment: use `uint_least32_t`, which is required to exist in C99 implementations, and ignore all but the rightmost 24 bits (ie, work modulus `1<<24`) -- this will work even if `uint_least32_t` is actually 36 or 48 or 64... bytes wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just mask a larger integer type with the right bit pattern to 24 bits if you need only 24 bits, something like this

```
int main(int argv, char** argc) {
    uint32_t i = 42 & 0xFFFFFF;

    return 0;
}
```

or you could use the C [union type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) with 24 bits you can only have 24 bits.