# Getting a 128 bits integer from command line

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bit-manipulation, 128-bit

I'm trying to cast an `unsigned long long` key to do the [Tiny Encryption Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    unsigned int key[4] = { 0 };
    *key = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    printf("%s key = %llu\n", argv[0], key);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my input :

```
./a.out 9223372036854775700
```

Here is the output :

```
./a.out key = 140723741574976
```

So I'm passing a 128 bit key in `argv[1]`. Shouldn't it be cast properly in memory into the `unsigned int` array?

So, I'm trying to figure out why this is the output of my program. Does this have something to do with endianness?

Comment: when you write code where you need your types to have some exact size you are better off by using more specific types like `__int128` (assuming you use GCC, where this is supported) as it is not system-dependent

Comment: I can't controll the return value of strtoll() function. Casting it into __int128 would be useless right?

Comment: There are serious problems in your code.  One, `printf("%s key = %llu\n", argv[0], key);` emits the *address* of the `key` array, but with the incorrect `%llu` format specifier, which is undefined behavior.  Two, if `key` is an `int` array, `*key` refers to an `int` value, not a `long long` value.  You're only storing data into the *first* member of your array.  And you don't seem to have a `#include <stdlib.h>` line, so the resulting implicit declaration of `strtoll()` means the compiler assumes it returns `int`.

Comment: Well, how could I get store a 128 bits integer in an unsigned long array from `argv[1]`?

Comment: Long story short: C doesn't really support integers larger than 64 bits. You need to use a "big int" or "bignum" library, as you'd find in many crypto libraries.

Comment: It is true you cannot control the size of the returning value of `stroll()`, which is at least 64 bits but not 128 bits guaranteed. However, that's always gonna be a bottleneck. What I am saying is use a type of 128 bits rather than an array as then it will actually work in some systems (eg x64)

Comment: The things is that I need to cut that number into four parts (as the algorithm needs it).

Comment: I think you should have mentioned that, too. Let me edit my answer then to split key into four parts

Comment: `9223372036854775700` is a 63 bit number.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart technically C doesn't specify the maximum range of any types

Comment: @Lưu No, but `<stdint.h>` defines `uint64_t` but not `uint128_t`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that depends on implementation. It's completely possible that an implementation is allowed to have [uint24_t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377903/995714) or uint128_t. Besides, as I said, there's no defined maximum value in C so it's possible that even `short int` has 128 bits in some implementation

Comment: The question is posed incorrectly. OP does not actually need a 128 bit unsigned integer type; they have a string containing a nonnegative integer between 0 and 2¹²⁸-1, inclusive, which they need to *parse into four 32-bit unsigned integer parts*. Because that's what the key is in Tiny Encryption Algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a step back, and look at what you are trying to implement. The Tiny Encryption Algorithm does not work on an 128-bit integer, but on a 128-bit key; the key is composed of four 32-bit unsigned integers.

What you actually need, is a way to parse a decimal (or hexadecimal, or some other base) 128-bit unsigned integer from a string to four 32-bit unsigned integer elements.

I suggest writing a multiply-add function, which takes the quad-32-bit value, multiplies it by a 32-bit constant, and adds another 32-bit constant:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t muladd128(uint32_t quad[4], const uint32_t mul, const uint32_t add)
{
    uint64_t  temp = 0;

    temp = (uint64_t)quad[3] * (uint64_t)mul + add;
    quad[3] = temp;

    temp = (uint64_t)quad[2] * (uint64_t)mul + (temp >> 32);
    quad[2] = temp;

    temp = (uint64_t)quad[1] * (uint64_t)mul + (temp >> 32);
    quad[1] = temp;

    temp = (uint64_t)quad[0] * (uint64_t)mul + (temp >> 32);
    quad[0] = temp;

    return temp >> 32;
}
```

The above uses most significant first word order. It returns nonzero if the result overflows; in fact, it returns the 32-bit overflow itself.

With that, it is very easy to parse a string describing a nonnegative 128-bit integer in binary, octal, decimal, or hexadecimal:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void clear128(uint32_t quad[4])
{
    quad[0] = quad[1] = quad[2] = quad[3] = 0;
}

/* muladd128() */

static const char *parse128(uint32_t quad[4], const char *from)
{
    if (!from) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    while (*from == '\t' || *from == '\n' || *from == '\v' ||
           *from == '\f' || *from == '\r' || *from == ' ')
        from++;

    if (from[0] == '0' && (from[1] == 'x' || from[1] == 'X') &&
        ((from[2] >= '0' && from[2] <= '9') ||
         (from[2] >= 'A' && from[2] <= 'F') ||
         (from[2] >= 'a' && from[2] <= 'f'))) {
        /* Hexadecimal */
        from += 2;
        clear128(quad);

        while (1)
            if (*from >= '0' && *from <= '9') {
                if (muladd128(quad, 16, *from - '0')) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return NULL;
                }
                from++;
            } else
            if (*from >= 'A' && *from <= 'F') {
                if (muladd128(quad, 16, *from - 'A' + 10)) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return NULL;
                }
                from++;
            } else
            if (*from >= 'a' && *from <= 'f') {
                if (muladd128(quad, 16, *from - 'a' + 10)) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return NULL;
                }
                from++;
            } else
                return from;
    }

    if (from[0] == '0' && (from[1] == 'b' || from[1] == 'B') &&
        (from[2] >= '0' && from[2] <= '1')) {
        /* Binary */
        from += 2;
        clear128(quad);

        while (1)
            if (*from >= '0' && *from <= '1') {
                if (muladd128(quad, 2, *from - '0')) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return NULL;
                }
                from++;
            } else
                return from;
    }

    if (from[0] == '0' &&
        (from[1] >= '0' && from[1] <= '7')) {
        /* Octal */
        from += 1;
        clear128(quad);

        while (1)
            if (*from >= '0' && *from <= '7') {
                if (muladd128(quad, 8, *from - '0')) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return NULL;
                }
                from++;
            } else
                return from;
    }

    if (from[0] >= '0' && from[0] <= '9') {
        /* Decimal */
        clear128(quad);

        while (1)
            if (*from >= '0' && *from <= '9') {
                if (muladd128(quad, 10, *from - '0')) {
                    errno = ERANGE;
                    return NULL;
                }
                from++;
            } else
                return from;
    }

    /* Not a recognized number. */
    errno = EINVAL;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint32_t key[4];
    int      arg;

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        const char *end = parse128(key, argv[arg]);
        if (end) {
            if (*end != '\0')
                printf("%s: 0x%08x%08x%08x%08x (+ \"%s\")\n", argv[arg], key[0], key[1], key[2], key[3], end);
            else
                printf("%s: 0x%08x%08x%08x%08x\n", argv[arg], key[0], key[1], key[2], key[3]);
            fflush(stdout);
        } else {
            switch (errno) {
            case ERANGE:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Too large.\n", argv[arg]);
                break;
            case EINVAL:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not a nonnegative integer in binary, octal, decimal, or hexadecimal notation.\n", argv[arg]);
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It is very straightforward to add support for Base64 and Base85, which are sometimes used; or indeed for any base less than 2<sup>32</sup>.

And, if you think about the above, it was all down to being precise about what you need.

Answer (score 3):

`long long` is only specified to contain at least 64 bits. You might be better off passing your key as hex and parsing it manually into a byte array

Answer (score 1):

Code is attempting to print the address of the array `key[0]` rather than its value.  This is not an endian-ness issue.  Enable all compiler warnings to save time.

`*key = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 10);` attempts to save a `long long` (at least 64-bit) into a `unsigned int`, which is likely only 32.

The string "9223372036854775700" represents a 63 bit number.

First try to use an `unsigned long long` which is at least a 64-bit number.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    // unsigned int key[4] = { 0 };
    unsigned long long  key = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    printf("%s key = %llu\n", argv[0], key);
    return 0;
}
```

---

C does not specify support for 128-bit integers.  User code could be written to cope with that.  [@C_Elegans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716086/2410359) idea of using hexadecimal text is  good.

As `int` could be of various sizes, better to use

```
#include <stdint.h>

// unsigned int key[4];
uint32_t key[4];
```

---

A sample code idea

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  uint16_t u[8];
} my_uint128_t;

my_uint128_t strtomy_uint128(const char *s, char **endptr, int base) {
  my_uint128_t y = {0};
  while (isalnum((unsigned char ) *s)) {
    char *endptr;
    uint32_t sum = (uint32_t) strtoul((char[2]) {*s, '\0'}, &endptr, base);
    if (*endptr) {
      break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      sum +=  y.u[i] * (uint32_t) base;
      y.u[i] = (uint16_t) sum;
      sum >>= 16;
    }
    if (sum) {
      errno = ERANGE;
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        y.u[i] = UINT16_MAX;
      }
    }
    s++;
  }
  if (endptr) {
    *endptr = (char *) s;
  }
  return y;
}

void uint128_dump(my_uint128_t x) {
  for (int i = 8; i > 0; ) {
    i--;
    printf("%04" PRIX16 "%c", x.u[i], i ? ' ' : '\n');
  }
}

int main(void) {
  my_uint128_t a = strtomy_uint128("9223372036854775700", 0, 10);
  uint128_dump(a);
}
```

Output

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 7FFF FFFF FFFF FF94
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it manually? Get a `__int128` type variable, go through each digit of your input and insert it in your variable as such:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    __int128 key = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(argv[1]); i++){

        key *= 10; // "shift" current value to make space for adding one more decimal
        key += argv[1][i] - '0'; // convert ascii character to number 

    }

    printf("%s key = %llu\n", argv[0], key);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if `argv[1]` is too long the key will discard its first digits rather than its last. So, maybe that's something you need to take care of too, according to your preferences